# How to make likes updateable without registration?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I made a code that adds likes and shows their number on the screen.

But there is a problem, when you download the application on 2 devices and press the button at the same time, then only one like is counted. How can I fix this without implementing registration?

There is an idea to make fields that will be created for everyone on the phone when the like is pressed and this number will be added to the total, but I do not know how to implement this.

Here's the current code:

```
struct LikeCounts {
    var likecount: String
}

class LikeTextModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var likecounts: LikeCounts!
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init() {
        updateLike()
    }
    
    func updateLike() {
        
        db.collection("likes").document("LikeCounter")
            .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
                guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                guard let data = document.data() else {
                    print("Document data was empty.")
                    return
                }
                if let likecount = data["likecount"] as? String  {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.likecounts = LikeCounts(likecount: likecount)
                    }
                }
            }
    }

@ObservedObject private var likeModel = LikeTextModel()

if self.likeModel.likecounts != nil{
                            Button(action:
                                    {self.like.toggle()
                                        like ? addlike(): dellike()
                                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.like, forKey: "like")
                            }) {
                                Text((Text(self.likeModel.likecounts.likecount))}

func addlike() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let like = Int.init(self.likeModel.likecounts.likecount)
    db.collection("likes").document("LikeCounter").updateData(["likecount": "\(like! + 1)"]) { (err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err)
            return
        }
    }
    }
    func dellike() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let like = Int.init(self.likeModel.likecounts.likecount)
    db.collection("likes").document("LikeCounter").updateData(["likecount": "\(like! - 1)"]) { (err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err)
            return
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has the ability to reliably increment a value, like this:

```
db.collection('likes').doc('LikeCounter')
  .updateData([
    "likecount": FieldValue.increment(1)
  ]);
```

Comment: The field name needs to be in quotes, so `"likecount".

Comment: I made Int64, but now it fails in view. https://imgur.com/wGIkavK  https://imgur.com/JCj62bQ